# Не могу подключить второе приложение в Django

Tags: python, django

Есть у меня в проекте 2 приложения main и sysAccaunts.В общем, суть проблемы такая, что хочу создать второе приложение для сайта. Все как нужно подключил в settings, сделал перенаправление в главном urls и все такое. Но при переходе на новую ссылку к views нового приложения - вылетает ошибка 404.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя ранее я создавал приложение main, настроил все точно так же и оно работает.

Нагляднее выглядит это все так:

Главный Urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('reg/', include('sysAccaunts.urls'))
]
```

Urls из моего второго приложения sysAccaunts:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('reg/', views.index, name='reg')
]
```

sysAccaunts/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>HttpResponse</h1>");
```

В settings.py все подключается тоже

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main',
    'sysAccaunts'
]
```

Comment: `reg` и `reg/` это разные адреса. Если вы в urls.py написали `reg/` — значит и в браузере тоже косую черту добавьте

Comment: Хотя вообще Django по умолчанию добавляет его автоматически. У вас включен CommonMiddleware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

всё правильно. Перейдите в `http://127.0.0.1/reg/reg/` и увидите вашу страницу. Вы прописываете url'ы так: все что начинается с `reg/` обрабатывается уже вторым  файлом `urls`, который в sysAccounts. А на этой странице показываются только записи из главного urls. Чтобы посмотреть пути после `reg/`, добавьте в конце слеш

Comment: Понял, благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте убрать из главного urls.py в последней строчке reg/.